# Unix sub string replace in the file

Tags: regex, sed

I have `abc.txt` file that has below entries. I would like to replace substring of the sentence that begins with `"test"` after the second colon (:) with given value.

Tried below:

```
echo test:abc.io/gng-cp:1.34.2-of1231 | sed 's/\([^test:]*:\).*/\11.333.555/g'
```

But it is giving:

```
test:1.333.555
```

Expected was:

```
test:abc.io/gng-cp:1.333.555
```

Input is:

```
abc.txt
=======
jnu
mango
vim
test:abc.io/gng-cp:1.34.2-of1231
```

Appreciate inputs on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The expression `[^test:]*` means: match zero or more of characters that are NOT in the set `{t, e, s, t, :}`, which is probably not what you want. You're passing the global `/g` modifier to the expression, even though you're only modifying the string once. Also, it's not clear where you're capturing the `abc.io/gng-cp` portion of the string to preserve it.

Try this:

```
sed 's/^\(test:[^:]*:\).*$/\11.333.555/' abc.txt
```

This will match a string starting with `test:` and preserve it and everything else between the two colons, replacing everything after the second colon with the new number string.

Comment: Thank you so much it working .. appreciate the help @mwp

Answer (score 0):

Following `awk` may also help you.

```
echo "test:abc.io/gng-cp:1.34.2-of1231" |  awk -v val="1.333.555" 'match($0,/:[^:]*/){print substr($0,1,RSTART+RLENGTH) val;next} 1' Input_file
```

Adding a non-one liner form of solution now.

```
echo "test:abc.io/gng-cp:1.34.2-of1231" |  awk -v val="1.333.555" '
match($0,/:[^:]*/){
  print substr($0,1,RSTART+RLENGTH) val;
  next}
1'
```